# Unable to subscribe the Observable on newThread

Tags: rx-java

This code works

```
Observable.range(0, 9)
    .subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
        public void call(Integer item) {
            LOG.debug("item:{}", item);
        }
});
```

getting: DEBUG: net.test.rx2.App - item:0 up to 9. But following one skips the subscription at all. Please advise how to catch the Observable.

```
Observable.range(0, 9)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
        public void call(Integer item) {
            LOG.debug("item:{}", item);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Both examples work fine for me. My guess is that you are testing this in the application's main method. The second example runs the observable on a new thread, as a consequence the main thread has no blocking statements anymore. Since nothing blocks the main thread, the JVM decides that the application can be terminated. You need to block the main thread somehow so that the JVM doesn't shut down your application prematurely (i.e. before any events are emitted by the Observable).

For example you can add a simple System.in.read statement to block the main thread:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Observable.range(0, 9)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
            public void call(Integer item) {
                LOG.debug("item:{}", item);
            }
        });

    System.in.read(); // block to prevent premature JVM shutdown
}
```

Now you should be able to observe the result of the observable expression.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right. How to return the processing to the main thread ? (in RxAndroid it looks like .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) )  I see toBlocking().[first,last,...] is there anything else?